# Stack Font awesome Icons with Vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, font-awesome

I'm trying to stack icons as explained here https://fontawesome.com/v5.15/how-to-use/on-the-web/styling/stacking-icons
but in my project i'm using `vuejs` and `vuetify` my icons are thus inside a `v-icon` element.

Here is what i tried :

```
<div class="fa-stack fa-2x">
   <v-icon>fas fa-camera fa-stack-1x</v-icon>
   <v-icon>fas fa-ban fa-stack-2x</v-icon>
</div>
```

It just show the icon one after the other and not stacked.

Any idea on what i'm missing ? Or is it possible at all ?

Comment: Seems this feature's not been added yet to `v-icon`. However, code from **fontawesome** doc works perfectly.

Comment: You seems to be right, I had hope I was the problem and not `v-icon`, if you post it as an answer i will accept it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Stacked Icons*** styling approach of ***Font Awesome*** apparently is not supported by Vuetify `v-icon` so far. The good news is you still can implement this feature just with regular HTML tags such as div, i, span, ..etc.

I have attached an example of 2 Vuetify buttons. One of them is implemented with the stacked icons and the other one with Vuetify `v-icon`.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),

})
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/babel-polyfill/dist/polyfill.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.5.1/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-row align="center" justify="space-around">

      <v-btn>
        search
        <span class="ml-2 fa-stack fa-1x">
        <i class="fas fa-square fa-stack-2x"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-search fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
        </span>
      </v-btn>

      <v-btn>
        search
        <v-icon class="ml-2">fas fa-search</v-icon>
      </v-btn>

    </v-row>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="position: relative;" class="mx-2">
  <v-icon style="position: absolute; top: 8px; left:8px" dense color="white">
    $cloud
  </v-icon>
  <v-icon color="red" x-large>
    $ban
  </v-icon>
</div>
```

I was unable to get the accepted answer to work since I am doing the alternate way of loading font awesome icons. This does seem to work though - however I suggest making classes for the styles.

Update 2022-01-20
Apparently at some point font awesome renamed stack to layers so you can use the vue font awesome library components

```
        <font-awesome-layers class="fa-2x mx-2">
          <font-awesome-icon :icon="['fad', 'cloud']" transform="shrink-8 left-2" />
          <font-awesome-icon :icon="['fas', 'ban']" class="red--text" />
        </font-awesome-layers>
```